# Passar nome usuário para trigger de historico

Tags: spring-mvc

Estou tentando implementar uma *trigger* genérica para histórico de cadastro. Estou seguindo este link [Audit Trigger](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus) que funciona perfeitamente. O único problema é que eu não consigo passar o usuário que está fazendo as alterações.

Eu utilizo o *Spring MVC* e quando eu crio o *datasource* passo um usuário único assim no histórico todas alterações fica no nome do mesmo.

Tentei usar o comando SQL

```
set session myapp.usuario = 'usuarioLogado'
```

mas como é o Spring que controla as aberturas e fechamentos das minhas conexões ele reutiliza a mesma conexão assim o parâmetro `myapp.usuario` não fica correto.

Problema parecido como esses:

- [How can I set a username for a Postgresql audit trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126659/how-can-i-set-a-username-for-a-postgresql-audit-trigger)
- [Passing user id to PostgreSQL triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172524/passing-user-id-to-postgresql-triggers)

1 - Alguém já passou por estes problemas?

2 - Como eu posso criar histórico sem ter que ficar a cargo da aplicação de fazer isto?

Comment: `Como eu posso criar histórico sem ter que ficar a cargo da aplicação de fazer isto?` Dando permissão a cada usuário no banco de dados, porque **o único usuário que o banco enxerga é o da conexão feita com ele**. Não acho um bom caminho fazer isso.

Comment: @Renan O Problema é quem gerência as conexões é o _Spring_ e na hora de criar o _Datasource_ não tem como eu ficar trocando o usuário da conexão. Imagine que se eu logar como vander eu vou ter setar o usuário da conexão como tal. Outra pessoa loga no sistema como alex vou setar o usuário da conexão como alex? Sendo que pode ser até a mesma conexão, pois pelo que estou observando o _Spring_ não gera uma conexão nova a cada requisição feita e sim gerência as que ele tem e cria e fecha  conexões quando necessário.

Answer (score 2):

A definição do usuário deve ficar a cargo da aplicação mesmo, já que é ela quem controla as ações no banco de dados. A não ser que o banco de dados tivesse cadastrado cada usuário e a conexão usasse as respectivas credenciais.

Em geral, eu recomendaria auditoria na aplicação, pois é mais flexível do que diretamente no banco de dados.

Entretanto, sei que colocar auditoria no banco também tem lá suas vantagens, por exemplo no caso de alterações via script ou oriundas de outras sistemas.

E justamente por situações como essas é que fica complicado confiar num parâmetro definido pela aplicação. Esse acoplamento pode gerar problemas para alterações no banco que não venham pela aplicação.

Sem cogitar uma mudança mais profunda, podemos pensar em algumas formas de contornar essa situação.

Mas, primeiro, devemos entender que as conexões em uma aplicação web geralmente ficam num *pool* e são reutilizadas em diversas requisições, possivelmente por usuários diferentes.

## Definindo o usuário sempre que for acessar o banco

Uma forma de contornar a situação é definindo o usuário no banco no início de cada método que vai acessar o banco de dados.

Para facilitar isso você poderia usar Orientação a Aspectos com o Spring AOP para interceptar todos os métodos de DAOs, por exemplo, de forma que o comando seja executado automaticamente.

Outra possibilidade de aplicação de AOP seria criar uma anotação `@Auditoria`. Então sempre que um método com essa anotação fosse executado, o usuário seria passado para o banco de dados.

## Encapsular a conexão

Outra alternativa seria criar um *bean* encapsulando a conexão, que executaria o comando definindo o usuário sempre que o mesmo fosse usado.

O escopo desse bean teria que ser de *request*, para ser recriado a cada requisição. Ele então iria recuperar uma conexão e definir o usuário.

O *bean* poderia implementar os métodos de `Connection` para facilitar a integração.

## Filtro com reaproveitamento de conexão

Uma terceira abordagem seria colocar um filtro de requisição na aplicação.

A cada requisição ele abre uma conexão e atualiza o nome do usuário.

Essa conexão teria que ser armazenada durante a requisição toda e usada por todos os métodos que acessam o banco de dados.

## Considerações

Enfim, tentei dar algumas ideias. Na verdade seria precisa averiguar com precisão como o sistema funciona para ñao acabar com gambiarras, mas espero ter ajudado a você pensar numa possível solução.

Comment: Ajudou sim. Muito obrigado pelas dicas. Continuei estudando e o caminho que estou tomando é o AOP e interceptar o que eu quero que gere histórico. Postei a dúvida porque achei que isso era até uma coisa básica, devido que quase todo sistema precisa de um histórico de alterações. Quando eu conseguir fazer o AOP irei postar a solução. Desde já obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde.

Optei fazer pelo *AOP* utilizando o *Aspectj*.
No caso eu tenho um *BaseDao* e fiz com que interceptasse os métodos antes que eles sejam executados assim eu pego a conexão e seto uma prorpiedade (vide [set](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/config-setting.html) para mais informações) e na minha trigger eu pego o valor destas propriedades.
Segue o código:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;

@Aspect
@Component
@Configurable
public class HistoricoAlteracaoAspect {
    @Before("execution(* net.empresateste.projeto.base.BaseDAO.*(..)) && args(bean)")
    public void beforeExecute(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object bean) {
        // public void beforeExecute(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object bean, String username) {
        if (joinPoint.getTarget() instanceof UsuarioDaoImpl) {
            UsuarioDaoImpl dao = (UsuarioDaoImpl) joinPoint.getTarget();
            HttpSession session = (HttpSession) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().resolveReference(RequestAttributes.REFERENCE_SESSION);
            Object userAtribute = session.getAttribute("user");
            if (userAtribute != null) {
                if (session.getAttribute("user") != null) {
                    String sql = "set session myapp.usuario = '" + userAtribute.toString().toLowerCase() + "';";
                    dao.getJdbcTemplate().execute(sql);
                    sql = "set session application_name = 'myapp';";
                    System.out.println("BEFORE HASHCODE " + userAtribute + " " + dao.getJdbcTemplate().hashCode());
                    dao.getJdbcTemplate().execute(sql);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado